# Keys and Values as two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with several columns. Each of the column headers is a unique category and the rows below it contain a list of items in that category. I would like to transform it into two columns. Ideally, the first column would have all of the items listed and the second column would have the corresponding category.

I feel like this should be simple but I'm hitting a brick wall.

[image]

Comment: you're looking for wide to long format change.

Comment: Please post the example as text so that it can be easily used in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.melt` function for that :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Birds": ["Eagle", "Swan", "Robi"],
    "Fish": ["cod", "salmon", "Haddock"],
    "Farm animals": ["Pig", "horse", "hen"]
})

df
```

[image: df]

```py
df = df.melt(value_vars=df.columns).rename(columns={"variable": "Categories", "value": "Animals"})
df
```

[image: df2]